# Ember-Data: Restful Put

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am am trying to do a simple restful put command. My problem is that I need to do a put command into a different end point to my store.

I have my rest adapter

```
    DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
    namespace: 'datastore'
});
```

I need to be able to call an end point, but not sure how to do it;

Something like,

```
store('foundItems', JSON)
```

Where foundItems is the end point.

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to create a custom RESTAdapter and override buildURL, this should help you start

```
App.PeopleAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://www.google.com',
  namespace: 'api/v1',

/**
Builds a URL for a given type and optional ID.

By default, it pluralizes the type's name (for example,
'post' becomes 'posts' and 'person' becomes 'people').

If an ID is specified, it adds the ID to the path generated
for the type, separated by a `/`.

@method buildURL
@param {String} type
@param {String} id
@returns String
*/
buildURL: function(type, id) {
 var url = [],
     host = get(this, 'host'),
     prefix = this.urlPrefix();

 if (type) { url.push(this.pathForType(type)); }
 if (id) { url.push(id); }

 if (prefix) { url.unshift(prefix); }

 url = url.join('/');
 if (!host && url) { url = '/' + url; }

 return url;
},

});
```